# Force a merge in TFS after conflicts have been resolved

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, tfs

TFS 2010, VS 2010

We have a situation in TFS where a developer has not been following proper merge procedure.  When I run a compare of his developer directory against trunk, I get a number of files marked as either different or not in trunk at all.  The last merge/check-in to trunk was by him on 2011-05-26, and his last check-in to his dev branch was 2011-05-25.

I believe two things are going on:

1. He isn't updating his dev branch from trunk properly (we require developers to merge trunk -> dev branch and compile before merging dev -> trunk)
2. He isn't resolving merge conflicts correctly

The problem is that once he's marked conflicts as resolved, subsequent merges ignore those differences.  I need to force a merge that revisits the differences from the whole file so that I can manually update every change he's made.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You need to go to the command line and use `tf merge /force` e.g. `tf merge $/TeamProject/DevBranch $/TeamProject/Trunk /force` This should do what you want.

for more info try `tf msdn` which will open a browser and take you to the online help for the tf command tools.

`/recursive` fixes all and displays the GUI for conflicts.

Comment: How are conflicts resolved when run from the command line?  Is there still a windowed component to let me merge these visually?

Comment: Yes, you need to start the process from the command line but any conflicts are resolved using the GUI. It may be worth using the /preview option from the command line as well. This will give you an idea of what the merge will do.

Comment: I can't seem to make it work... I had to cd to the development directory from the command line to get tf to figure out the correct server... but no matter how I try to specify the version (required for /force), it seems to be trying to merge the very first version in the dev branch

Comment: tf merge /force /preview /version:C197309 $/CSA/Dev/Workflow $/CSA/Trunk/Source 
results in 
merge: $/CSA/Dev/Workflow;C3614~C3614 -> $/CSA/Trunk/Source;C3602 
Also, no GUI appears... do I launch Visual Studio to work with the changes?

Comment: @JamesReed - in case you get a moment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33003274/revoking-tfs-merge-credits

Answer (score 10):

I found your answer and comments most helpful. I wanted to add that I needed to remove the /preview option to finally open the conflict resolution UI.

```
tf merge /recursive /force /version:C5367 "$/Source" "$/Target"
```